# Logo upload is disabled for work experiences

Tags: support, status-bydesign, developer-story

Click to add a logo section is disabled on my work experiences.

Is this because company is mapped to [organization page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/310720/hepsiburada-com?storyType=1)?

If so, how can i add logo to organization page or to my developer story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click the X on the company / organization page, then upload the new logo.

[image]

We discourage this by default, because by changing company details you're creating a new list, from which you're the only member of. Other users will eventually join if they find your list to be more accurate.

*Your* story is something you might share publicly or with potential employers and we want the stories to be under your control only. By this we prevent other users from changing the appearance of your carefully created story.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to keep company page on my story. Is there any function that will allow me to add logo to company pages?

Comment: No, because that would imply changing the company logo for all the other users in that company. We are thinking about ways to make this happen within a list, but we haven't found a good solution yet, any input would be appreciated there. But keep in mind that the top priority here is not to change anything another user has entered, without their consent.